# How to write CDATA in php

Tags: php, cdata

I need to value a string in PHP using CDATA to pass it to a Web service. I don't use XML, but I'm using the JSON interface. When I write `$string = <![CDATA [blah blah blah]]>`, then if I print it I get an empty string.

Comment: sorry I tried to write CDATA with data inside '' and I have the same behaviour of php :)

Comment: $cdata = <![CDATA[$type=CURRICULUM_VITAE&codfiscale=' . $codfiscale.']]>; var_dump($cdata); And var_dump returns an empty string: the string is inside ''.

Comment: are you looking at the output in a browser? If so, check the page source please. what does it say? And what is the number in the var_dump saying? If it doesnt say string(0), then the string is not empty.

Comment: Yes it's true: If I see the page source I see the correct data. But web service doesn't work. I put CDATA because I had problems with &, I don't know how to communicate with it!

Comment: you cannot have a literal `&` in XML because it starts an entity. You have to encode any literal `&` as `&amp;` (ampersand)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $string = <![CDATA [blah blah blah]]>
```

Is invalid PHP code. You need to define a string (at least I guess you want that) *properly*:

```
$string = '<![CDATA [blah blah blah]]>';
```

If you need to use `'` characters inside your string, you need to escape them. See http://php.net/string.

Comment: If I put '' I am not able to see CDATA in the page browser: anyway I used ''. The correct answer was @Gordon I didn't see the page source.

Comment: The original problem was that you're creating a syntax error. Next to that it always depends where you view things. Inside the browser window/tab it's rendered, so already processed. View source helps here naturally to view the source (non-rendered and unprocessed).

Comment: @hakre while its true that the example code shown is invalid php, i understood this to be just that: a (sloppy) example.